# I can't upload data from my app to dropbox

Tags: dropbox-api

I can't upload data from my app to dropbox. I always gets this error:

```
 'Error in call to API function "files/upload": HTTP header "Dropbox-API-Arg": path: \'\\Songs\\539f67c172ec78e3f7608a64537616a5.mp3\' did not match pattern \'(/(.|[\\r\\n])*)|(ns:[0-9]+(/.*)?)|(id:.*)\'',
```

I created dropbox app, generated app access token and added token in my env file.

```
const uploadSong = async (file, song) => {
    const destination = path.join(process.env.DROPBOX_UPLOAD_PATH, song.asset_sound.fileNameFull);
    console.log('Uploading to DROPBOX ...', destination);
    return  await dbx.filesUpload({ path: destination, contents: file.buffer, mode: 'overwrite'});
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The path you're supplying to the `path` parameter of `filesUpload` should be the remote Dropbox path where you want to upload the file. It should be formatted like `'/path/to/file.ext'`.

You're supplying something like `'\Songs\539f67c172ec78e3f7608a64537616a5.mp3'`. I imagine you mean to supply something like `'/Songs/539f67c172ec78e3f7608a64537616a5.mp3'` instead.